# Why is this Statement correct: G implies ¬Contradiction?

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 110. [*Sweet Reason: A Field Guide to Modern Logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444337157) (2010 2 ed) by Henle, Garfield, Tymoczko.</sub>

> The following statements are all about schools. Here is some partial information:
>   A is true at Sophist College
>   B is false at Stoic University.
>   C is consistent (i.e. its true at some school).
>   D is contingent.
>   E is a contradiction.
>   F implies B.
>   [No information is supplied about G.]
>
> For each of the following statements respond Y if the statement is correct, N if the 
>   statement is incorrect, or I if there is not enough information to decide whether or not it is 
>   correct.
>
> 17. G implies ¬E.
>
> [Answer on p 357, and [online](http://sweetreason2ed.com/answer5.html) for Section 5.3 too:] 17. Y

My initial answer was I: we do not know the truth value of G or ¬E, because per the following definition, ¬E means that not every line of E's truth table is false (= ≥ 1 line is true).

> [p 109:] If a wff [Well-formed Formula] is false on every line of its truth table we say it's a **contradiction**.

So I was stupefied to see the answer as Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the truth table of a contradiction E, all lines are false. Then, in the truth table of ¬E, all lines must be ¬false, i.e. true.

Since G → ¬E ≡ ¬G ∨ ¬E, and we know that ¬E is *always* true, the implication must be as well.

You were wrong in deriving from the quoted definition that

> ¬E means that not every line of E's truth table is false (= ≥ 1 line is true)

You could say that a statement is *not* a contradiction iff there is at least one line true. However, this is a meta-theorem about propositions and truth tables, which does not give you the truth table of a negated proposition.

Answer (score 1):

A statement of the form *P* → *Q* where *Q* is true is always true, regardless of the truth value of *P*: it is said to be [trivially true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_%28mathematics%29#Trivial_proofs).